# Android Development: Class That Creates an Object, Calls Some Methods Then Returns That Object (How?)

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering how I'd go about making a class, let's call it Class Master, where:
- You call Class Master and it calls Class A, and calls some of that Class A's methods, then returns Class A so you can call methods from the returned Class A where ever you called Class Master.

Basically, I want to turn this code:

```
//Create FTPClient object and connect
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient(); 
ftpClient.connect(server);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.login(username);
ftpClient.listFiles("/");
```

Into this code:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new ftpConnection(); //Connects, enters passive mode and logs in then returns the FTPClient object we created so we can do other stuff with it, like below:
ftpClient.listFiles("/");
```

So that I can have one single call that I can use in different activites to connect to an FTP, if you understand what I mean.

I tried myself but I didn't get the desired effect for some reason (don't have the code I tried anymore)

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2):

Use the factory design pattern:

```
public class ftpClientFactory {
    public ftpClientFactory(){}

    public FTPClient getNewClient(){
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient(); 
        ftpClient.connect(server);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.login(username);
        return ftpClient;
    }
}
```

To use:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new ftpClientFactory().getNewClient();
ftpClient.listFiles("/");
```

Comment: If I put this in a seperate .java class, will it have to extend Activity for me to be able to use it in other activities?

Comment: No it need not be an activity. Where you can use it depends on what you decide to import from in other classes. Importing the package containing this class should be enough.

Comment: I don’t understand why you should have to instanciate a new object. I’d rather declare `getNewClient()` to be a static method and then use `FTPClient ftpClient = ftpClientFactory.getNewClient();`.

Comment: You don't have to. Making everything static breaks OOP a bit, but has it's uses. In this case, it's a trivial example, so yes, I'd agree. However if he wished to store specific FTPClient state, then stamping out the factory makes more sense. Also, if the factory was just a class that had a static method, it wouldn't be a factory.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a class contructor to create a ftp connection the class creation will take too long. You should run the ftp calls in an extra thread. If the UI thread is blocked too long by any call (i.e. network) the app will be interrupted because of an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html). That might be the reason why your solution is not working.

Anyway - you could create a static Method in any class, like:

```
class MyMaster{
    static FTPClient doAllThatCrazyStuffAndGetMeThatFTPClient(){
         FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient(); 
         ftpClient.connect(server);
         ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
         ftpClient.login(username);
         ftpClient.listFiles("/");
         return ftpclient;
    }
}
```

And then call the static method from anywhere in your code:

```
FTPClient connectedClient = MyMaster.doAllThatCrazyStuffAndGetMeThatFTPClient();
```

Or maybe you are looking for the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It lets you also save state information. So you can use the very same connection anywhere. But don't create [memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)!

Comment: I have the code in an AsyncTask with a progressDialog showing in my current code anyway, just needed to find out how to be able to use the same code to connect across different activities. Thanks for the answer :D!